# Trying to make a graph on google sheets that relies off of other data points

Tags: google-sheets, filter, graph, charts, pie-chart

I have a set of survey data from a google form in google sheets, and I want to plot the results on some graphs. I know how to graph one column of data, but I am curious how I would graph a chart of answers BASED ON other answers. For example, if you look at this [Example Data Set,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHDYs.png) imagine that I am trying to plot the favorite color of all people born in January. With a sample this small it could easily be done manually, but the actual set I am working with is much bigger so manually sorting is not an option. Any way to do this in google sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select columns A, B and C, and set filter:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]